# Generate field in MySQL SELECT

Tags: sql, mysql

If I've got a table containing Field1 and Field2 can I generate a new field in the select statement? For example, a normal query would be:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table
```

And I want to also create Field3 and have that returned in the resultset... something along the lines of this would be ideal:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 = 'Value' FROM Table
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, 'Value' Field3 FROM Table
```

or for clarity

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, 'Value' AS Field3 FROM Table
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes - it's very possible, in fact you almost had it!
Try:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, 'Value' AS `Field3` FROM Table
```